# how can I prevent apps from immediately connect upon wifi connection

Tags: wi-fi, vpn

I often have to connect to public wifi networks, and upon connecting (automatically or otherwise), several apps will immediately connect to their host server and start exchanging data. How can I make sure that those apps will not start anything until I have my VPN turned on ? Even if I have my VPN auto-connecting, there is still a [sometime longer] delay during which other apps will start "chatting" on the net..........

I'd like to be able to give the go before apps automatically connect to the net. Some will let me configure a "connect on demand" but most will connect whenever they can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 8 there's built-in option Block connections without VPN in VPN settings.

In other case you may use AFWall+ (root required) from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/dev.ukanth.ufirewall/) or [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall&hl=en) to allow apps to connect to internet only through VPN (only paid version supports VPN).

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by "Force stop" apps from app manager before connecting to wifi network that will prevent apps bring in background until you open them. Only that will be pain in the ass process because you will need to do that for every app you want to prevent using wifi until connect to vpn. You can try geenify or some app to stop background processes if you have a lot of apps.

Answer (score -3):

Go to settings, then click WiFi or WLAN
Then press the extra option button,then you click advanced setting , then switch off scanning always be avaliable. It will prevent any app from using wifi.

If that doesn't work switch on app permission an deny all apps wifi access.

If it doesn't work, I suggest you see a phone technician.

Comment: What scaning have to do with this?